# Showing error Cannot read property 'style' of undefined

Tags: javascript

```
function InitMenu() {
    var bar = menuBar.children
    for (var i = 0; i < bar.length; i++) {
        var menu = eval(bar[i].menu) menu.style.visibility = "hidden"
        bar[i].onmouseover = new Function("ShowMenu(" + bar[i].id + ")") var Items = menu.children
        for (var j = 0; j < Items.length; j++) {
            var menuItem = eval(Items[j].id) if (menuItem.menu != null) {
                menuItem.innerHTML += "<Span Id=" + menuItem.id + "_Arrow class='Arrow'>4</Span>" //var tmp = eval(menuItem.id+"_Arrow")
                    // tmp.style.pixelLeft = menu.getBoundingClientRect().Right //- tmp.offsetWidth - 15
                FindSubMenu(menuItem.menu)
            }
            if (menuItem.cmd != null) {
                menuItem.onclick = new Function("Do(" + menuItem.id + ")")
            }
            menuItem.onmouseover = new Function("highlight(" + Items[j].id + ")")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: format your code and mark the line that has the error.

Comment: Please read [ask] and [mcve], and [edit] your post accordingly. You haven't even asked a question.

Comment: This code is so hacky...

Comment: This code is terrible, with all that evaluation happening.

Comment: We need some more context: how is `menuBar` initialised? Which HTML does it represent? Did you assign `menu` properties to those particular HTML elements?

Answer (score -1):

`eval` can only be used when the data is json object. I assume you have a menu within a div called "menuBar"

```
var menuBar=document.getElementById("menuBar");
function InitMenu() {
    var bar = menuBar.childNodes;
    for (var i = 0; i < bar.length; i++) {
        var menu = bar[i];
        menu.style.visibility = "hidden";
        bar[i].onmouseover = new Function("ShowMenu(" + bar[i].id + ")") var Items = menu.children
        for (var j = 0; j < Items.length; j++) {
            var menuItem = eval(Items[j].id) if (menuItem.menu != null) {
                menuItem.innerHTML += "<Span Id=" + menuItem.id + "_Arrow class='Arrow'>4</Span>" //var tmp = eval(menuItem.id+"_Arrow")
                    // tmp.style.pixelLeft = menu.getBoundingClientRect().Right //- tmp.offsetWidth - 15
                FindSubMenu(menuItem.menu)
            }
            if (menuItem.cmd != null) {
                menuItem.onclick = new Function("Do(" + menuItem.id + ")")
            }
            menuItem.onmouseover = new Function("highlight(" + Items[j].id + ")")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You initial claim is wrong, and this is not solving the question as why there is this error popping up. You did also no indicate what you changed in the code and why that change is answering the question.

Comment: I think object is null. thats why it shows 'style' of undefined

Comment: Yes, but what is the cause?

Comment: bar [i] is undefined. So he can not style

Comment: How come `bar[i]` is undefined? The Asker has not provided enough information to know the cause of the issue.

Comment: Sorry, ... that what is the case?